# Is it possible to run plugin code when a multisite blog is deleted?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I have a plugin that creates tables when activated or when a new blog is added to a network. When a blog is deleted I would like to be able to remove those tables for that blog. Is there a hook available to do this?

I imagine it would be something similar to wpmu_new_blog, but I can't find an equivalent for deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `wpmu_delete_blog` in `/wp-admin/includes/ms.php` has an action hook called `delete_blog`. This hook passes the variable of `$blog_id`

You could try plugging into that hook, although it is executed right at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Thank you!  Even more interesting is that the function is identifying tables to drop based on the table prefix, then using apply_filters to allow modifying the list. Looks like I can just add my tables using the filter and have wpmu_delete_blog delete them for me. If this works I'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

This is arguably the better way to do it if you're just deleting tables, but *nothingtosee's* answer is also valid, and would be the required way if you need to do something besides dropping tables.

```
add_filter("wpmu_drop_tables", "DropTablesForBlog");


function DropTablesForBlog($tables)
{
  global $wpdb;

  $tables[] = $wpdb->prefix . "my_plugin_table_1";
  $tables[] = $wpdb->prefix . "my_plugin_table_2";
  $tables[] = $wpdb->prefix . "my_plugin_table_2";

  return $tables;
}
```

Comment: I guess this should be the accepted answer since this is the cleaner way to do it.